# Angular overflow hidden when navbar is opened

Tags: angular

Hello i have navbar like this which is in custom component

```
<nav id="navbar" [ngClass]="isOpened ? 'opened-navbar' : 'disabled-navbar'">
```

....

Thing is i would like to hide body overflow when navbar is opened smthing like

```
body.opened-navbar{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

is something like this possible using just css?

Comment: here you are trying to style the parent based on the child element's class/condition. Which is not possible with pure css.

Comment: you can use a variable 'isOpened' to add a custom class to both body and nav and later you can add expected style tags to particular css class.